# Moving a ton of files from Box to a Google Storage Bucket directly?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, box

I'm seeing that I can transfer files to drive then on to a google bucket, but is there a better way to accomplish this. I have maybe a few gb's of data.

Comment: Where are stored the file now? Do you have the file locally?

Comment: I have some files locally but not all. It's also a mix of files, like code, docs, images

Comment: What's box? An online service?